# Heroku Post Request is working on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I tried to publish a small Rest Service using Heroku. 
The problem I'm having is, the post request loginU works when I try from Postman for my localhost, but when I deploy it to heroku, it doesn't.
[image]

```
 @PostMapping("/loginU")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> loginUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        Student current = null;
        try {
            String username = user.getUsername();
            String password = user.getPassw();
            current = gpaCalculator.getStudent(username, password);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(current);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(current);
        }

    }
```

and the request is like :

[image]

By the way, this is the old request I was using which works both for my localhost and heroku link. I 'm new to Spring and Heroku. So, why is this happenning? I would be glad if you could help, thanks!

```
  @PostMapping("/loginUser")
    public ResponseEntity getGrades(@RequestParam(value="username") String username, @RequestParam(value="passw") String password) {

        Student current = null;
        try {current = gpaCalculator.getStudent(username, password);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(current);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(current);
        }

    }
```

herokuURL : https://kugpacalculator.herokuapp.com/

heroku logs:

```
2020-02-05T14:03:56.133012+00:00 app[web.1]: 14:03:56.132 [http-nio-34176-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - POST "/loginU", parameters={}
2020-02-05T14:03:56.140330+00:00 app[web.1]: 14:03:56.140 [http-nio-34176-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-02-05T14:03:56.141139+00:00 app[web.1]: 14:03:56.141 [http-nio-34176-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found
2020-02-05T14:03:56.141259+00:00 app[web.1]: 14:03:56.141 [http-nio-34176-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-02-05T14:03:56.150004+00:00 app[web.1]: 14:03:56.149 [http-nio-34176-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
```

Comment: Seems `gpaCalculator` method throws an exception, what does this method do?

Comment: can you please post your localhost url and heroku URL for understand

Comment: @B.M gpaCalculator is trying to login with the user credentials to the university's system and get the Student's information by web scraping, but I don't think it's the cause of my problem since I'm getting a path not found error :/

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni herokuURL --> https://kugpacalculator.herokuapp.com/ and the other one is the local Tomcat server localhost:5000